# how can i continue my previous function that hasn't been finished in python-telegram-bot?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

so im devepoling a python telegram bot using `python-telegram-bot` library, and it looks like i have a problem with my oython program, heres my code:

```
from telegram import *
from telegram.ext import *
from telegram.ext.filters import Filters
from requests import *
import os
import time
import random

buttons = []

def cls():
  os.system('cls' if os.name=='nt' else 'clear');
cls();
print("Bot is online")

updater = Updater('bot-token', use_context = True);

def start(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
  update.message.reply_text(f"Hello {update.message.chat.first_name}\n\nUse the /help command to see what the bot can do");
  requests.post("https://api.telegram.org/bot<bot-token>/sendMessage?chat_id=-759205346&text=@%s\t:\t%s" % (update.message.chat.username, update.message.text));
  
def help(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
  helpcmd = update.message.text;
  helpcmd = helpcmd[6:];
  
  if helpcmd == 'help':
    update.message.reply_text("**HELP**\n\nThis command will display all the commands that available");
  elif helpcmd == 'donate':
    update.message.reply_text("**DONATE**\n\nYou can use this command to donate to the orphans and helpless peoples!");
  elif not helpcmd:
    update.message.reply_text(f"Hello {update.message.chat.first_name}!\n\nHere some commands that you can use:\n\n⚙️General:\n\n\t/help\t/donate\n\nTo see more details about a command use /help <command>");
  else:
    update.message.reply_text(f"Sorry, the command ({helpcmd}) that your are trying to search is invalid, please type the correct command")
  
  requests.post("https://api.telegram.org/bot5367528012:AAHKs28Gw22it1hjnfBx3AQ1krgZaRhf4OM/sendMessage?chat_id=-759205346&text=@%s\t:\t%s" % (update.message.chat.username, update.message.text));
  
def donate(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
  update.message.reply_text(f"Hello {update.message.chat.first_name} \n\nIf you want to donate, you can text @F4IPES!");
  update.message.reply_text("**Where did my money will go?**\n\nGood question! your maney will be donated to the helpless peoples, and the orphans!");
  requests.post("https://api.telegram.org/bot5367528012:AAHKs28Gw22it1hjnfBx3AQ1krgZaRhf4OM/sendMessage?chat_id=-759205346&text=@%s\t:\t%s" % (update.message.chat.username, update.message.text));
  
def parasite(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
  David = None
  Fay = None
  Zoey = None
  Xiq = None
  Jay = None
  Isle = None
  Chi = None
  Xiao = None
  Fai= None
  
  users = [David, Fay, Zoey, Xiq, Jay, Isle, Chi, Xiao, Fai]
  
  players = []
  player = update.message.chat.username
  medic = "medic"
  survivor = "suvivor"
  parasite = "parasite"
  roles = [medic, survivor, parasite]
  randroles = random.choices(roles, weights = [5, 8, 3], k = 6)
  
  for i in range(6):
    randuser = random.choice(users)
    players.append(randuser)
    users.remove(randuser)
    
  for i in range(6):
    players[i] = roles[i]
  
  ask = f"Welcome to Parasite {update.message.chat.first_name}\n\nAre you new into this game?"
  global buttons
  buttons = [[InlineKeyboardButton('Yes, I am new', callback_data='yes')], [InlineKeyboardButton('No, I am not new', callback_data='no')]]
  context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup(buttons), text=ask)

update.message.text_reply("Lets start the game!")
  
def queryhandler(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
  query = update.callback_query.data
  update.callback_query.answer()
  
  yesorno = None
  
  if 'yes' in query:
    yesorno = "Here are the rules of the game\n\n1.This game has 3 roles, medic, survivor, and parasite, you get this role randomly,there is 1 parasite among 6 peoples (you and 5 others), your goal is to find out who is the parasite, once you find out, you need to vote it out before the night falls, each night 1 person will get killed\n\n2.This game has three roles:\n\t\t- Medic\nThis role can heal other, in the night if the medic choose the right person to heal, if the person that the medic choose died in that night, the person that got healed will be alive again\n\n\t\t- Parasite\nThis role can kill anyone when the night falls but only one person, if the parasite got voted out, the survivors wins\n\n\t\t- Survivor\nThis role can not do anything other than finding out who is the parasite and vote the parasite out"
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text=yesorno)
    time.sleep(1)
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="Alright then lets get going!")
    time.sleep(1)
    parasiteStart()
  
  if 'no' in query:
    yesorno = "Alright then lets get going!"
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text=yesorno)
    time.sleep(1)
    parasiteStart()
  
def unknown(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
  update.message.reply_text(f"Sorry, {update.message.text} is not a valid command");
  requests.post("https://api.telegram.org/bot5367528012:AAHKs28Gw22it1hjnfBx3AQ1krgZaRhf4OM/sendMessage?chat_id=-759205346&text=@%s\t:\t%s" % (update.message.chat.username, update.message.text));
  
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
  
dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))
dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('help', help))
dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('donate', donate))
dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('parasite', parasite))

dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(queryhandler))

updater.dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, unknown));
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.command, unknown));

updater.start_polling();
```

So what the problem here is when the user clicked a button on the `parasite()` function which is this lines of code

```
context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup(buttons), text=ask)
```

it goes to the `queryhandler()` function which is this lines of code:

```
def queryhandler(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
  query = update.callback_query.data
  update.callback_query.answer()
  
  yesorno = None
  
  if 'yes' in query:
    yesorno = "Here are the rules of the game\n\n1.This game has 3 roles, medic, survivor, and parasite, you get this role randomly,there is 1 parasite among 6 peoples (you and 5 others), your goal is to find out who is the parasite, once you find out, you need to vote it out before the night falls, each night 1 person will get killed\n\n2.This game has three roles:\n\t\t- Medic\nThis role can heal other, in the night if the medic choose the right person to heal, if the person that the medic choose died in that night, the person that got healed will be alive again\n\n\t\t- Parasite\nThis role can kill anyone when the night falls but only one person, if the parasite got voted out, the survivors wins\n\n\t\t- Survivor\nThis role can not do anything other than finding out who is the parasite and vote the parasite out"
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text=yesorno)
    time.sleep(1)
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="Alright then lets get going!")
    time.sleep(1)
  
  if 'no' in query:
    yesorno = "Alright then lets get going!"
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text=yesorno)
    time.sleep(1)
```

to of course see what the program should do when the button is pressed, but when the program goes to the `queryhandler()` to read what it should do when a button is pressed in the `parasite()` function, it wont continue the program that didnt finished yet in the `parasite()` function

So what i want the program to do is when the program finished to read what it should do when a button in `parasite()` function in the `queryhandler()` function, i want the program to continue what it hasn't been finished in the `parasite()` function which is this line of code:

```
update.message.text_reply("Lets start the game!")
```

what the program actually do is, reading what is should do in the `queryhandler()` program when a button pressed in `parasite()` function, and then it ends, it didn't continue the program that hasn't been finished in the `parasite()` function

(If you didnt understand what im saying im so sorry, my english is bad lol)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot go and "continue" a function. I have a few suggestions for your code:

- Refactor the `parasite` function into a class. It initiates a new class and add it to a global array or a database and links it to the user's ID/Username. That way you can reference the object when needed.
- Or have the variables as global but that will only allow you to have one game running at a time. If another user wants to play, the game may crash.